# uncrustify C++: Transform multiple variable initialization per line posible?

Tags: c++, uncrustify

is it possible by using uncrustify to transform this:

```
int a, b, c, d=0;
```

to this :

```
int a;
int b;
int c;
int d=0;
```

Thanx

Comment: Oh I stand corrected. You're right.

Comment: What have you tried? How did it work (or not work)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not one of [the options](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/config.txt).

Such a thing would be more of a refactoring, than a simple tweak to spacing (which is mostly what this tool does).

There's no [open feature request](https://github.com/uncrustify/uncrustify/issues?page=1&q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3AFeatureRequest) for this at present, either; feel free to create one.